# how to select for records that drop off at a certain date, then reappear later?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with records that get verified yearly. What i'd like to check for are records that were verified before 3/01/2014, but then dropped off and were picked up on 3/11/2019.

For example where max date = 3/1/2014 before the 3/1/2019 was written to the same id. However the returned record must also include have the 3/1/2019 address included.

Mytable:

```
ID  |Date
1   |3/1/2011
1   |3/1/2012
1   |3/1/2013
1   |3/1/2014    
2   |3/1/2011
2   |3/1/2012
2   |3/1/2013
2   |3/1/2014
2   |3/1/2019
3   |3/1/2011
3   |3/1/2012
3   |3/1/2013
3   |3/1/2014
3   |3/1/2015
3   |3/1/2019
```

For the above example, I'd like ID 2 to return as its the only record that fits the criteria.

Result

```
ID
2
```

ID 1 does not include 3/1/2019 so it was excluded.

ID 3 has a max date of 3/1/2015 previous to the 3/1/2019 date and was excluded.

Comment: You are searching for the lag/lead functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(case when date < date '2019-11-03' then date end) < date '2014-03-01' and
       sum(case when date = date '2019-11-03' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

An alternative method  is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where date = date '2019-11-03' and
      prev_date < date '2019-03-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the syntax you have, but in postgresql you could write like this code, in mysql, if i am not mistaken, you should change lateral to apply etc.

```
SELECT distinct id from my_table a
left join lateral(select count(distinct date) b4 from my_table b where b.id=a.id and date<='3/01/2014') befor on true
left join lateral(select count(distinct date) aftr from my_table b where b.id=a.id and date>='3/11/2019') after on true
where b4>0 and aftr>0
```

Basically what i do is join the count of dates before and after said dates and then only show distinct ID's who have at both.

Answer (score 0):

#### Consider `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

There are lots of SQL ways to do this, some good ones have already been given.  Here is one that is (*very* arguably) more readable, once you are comfortable with the syntax.

You are looking for rows in your data that match a pattern.  Specifically, a row on or before 3/1/2014 followed immediately by a row for 3/1/2019, with nothing in between.

Anytime you are looking for rows that match a pattern, you can consider using the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause in your `SELECT`.  Here it is for your case:

```
SELECT id from mytable
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( OLDER RECENT )
  DEFINE
    RECENT AS RECENT.dte = TO_DATE('3/1/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'),
    OLDER AS OLDER.dte <= TO_DATE('3/1/2014','MM/DD/YYYY')
)
```

> ```
> +----+
> | ID |
> +----+
> |  2 |
> +----+
> ```

This is nice because you can change it to get more information without having to make too many changes to the overall approach.

For example, suppose you also wanted to know, for each `id` what was the date when the series dropped off.  (I.e., that was the last date on or before 3/1/2014 for which there was data).  That fits right in with only minor changes:

```
SELECT id, dropoff_date from mytable
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  MEASURES OLDER.dte AS dropoff_date
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( OLDER RECENT )
  DEFINE
    RECENT AS RECENT.dte = TO_DATE('3/1/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'),
    OLDER AS OLDER.dte <= TO_DATE('3/1/2014','MM/DD/YYYY')
)
```

> ```
> +----+--------------+
> | ID | DROPOFF_DATE |
> +----+--------------+
> |  2 | 01-MAR-14    |
> +----+--------------+
> ```